# Select list showing items not in model

Tags: ember.js

I have a model for my groups, which is basically the following fields:

- Name
- Users

I am populating a list in my template with the following

```
{{view "Ember.Select" content=model.users  optionValuePath="content.id" optionLabelPath="content.name" attributeBindingds="size" size="5"}}
```

I load all users in the system in the controller, as so:

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    users: [],

    init: function () {
        this._super();

        this.set('users', this.store.find('user'));
    })
})
```

All users are populated as follows:

```
{{view "Ember.Select" content=users  optionValuePath="content.id" optionLabelPath="content.name" attributeBindingds="size" size="5" }}
```

What is the most appropriate way of filtering the second select to contain only users that aren't in the first select - that is, to show users that do not exist in `model.users`

Comment: Do you have a jsbin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to @Oren's answer, but I think you will need to declare it a property and watch the content of users via `@each`

```
users: function(){
  return this.get('model.users').filter(function(user){
    return !users.contains(user);
  });
}.property('model.users.@each')
```

Comment: I have tried this - and it's not working. I get 'users' is undefined. I have renamed the function to 'filtered' and referenced filtered in the template.

Comment: I got it. The filter is done on the controllers users, the watch is on the models users. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a filter on your controller:

```
users: this.get('model.users').filter(function(user){
    return !users.contains(user);
});
```